# How to hide fancybox navigation arrows on mobile

Tags: mobile, fancybox

I've spent most of the day on this and got nowhere. On a mobile handset the gallery is displayed with the nav arrows superimposed on the image. These are not necessary since swipe is enabled and spoil the look of the image.

I need to hide the arrows for mobile only, is there a recommended way to do this? It seems like a common thing one might want to do, but I can't find anything current on the web.

I've tried some js code to alter the options for the library to no avail, and can't figure out how to do it with a media query to modify the css.

Comment: Add `@media` query for desired mobile resolution and hide arrows with `display: none;`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a fragment of the html that renders the arrow(s)

Answer (score -1):

There is an option `arrows` that you can use to toggle navigation arrows. You could set it by yourself for mobile devices or you can use handy `mobile` option, like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
   mobile : {
       arrows: false
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's saved me a lot of time!